# Question on lambda function - preparing for the exam

Tags: python

I need some clarification on lambda. I am preparing the for exam.

The sample question in the exam is as follows:

```py
def f(a,b):
    return b(b)

print (f(lambda x:x+1,0))
```

What is the output?

I tried it using the code and it gives me error. However if I change `return a(b)` it returns `1`.

How shall I interpret `return b(b)` or `return a(b)`?

The function does not pass any argument with values e.g. 0 or 1. From where they are taken?
Also what is the meaning of a(b).

Please help!

I tried it by putting code. However I don't understand what a(b) or b(a) in the code.

Comment: `return b(b)` is an error since `b` is an int and you can't call an `int` like it's a function. So, I guess there is no output, unless you count the error message.

Comment: Why don't you just try to run it? In an interpreter? But I don't need to run it to know it will raise `TypeError`, b isn't callable. You might wanted `a(b)`, which would just print `1`. I haven't run it at all.

Comment: "*I don't understand what a(b) or b(a) in the code.*" `a` and `b` are your function parameters. `a(b)` invokes the function passed as `a` (in your example, a lambda) with a single argument set to the value of `b`.

Comment: I have just run it to test my theory, and the exact wording is: `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have pointed out, the code:

```py
def f(a, b):
    return b(b)

print(f(lambda x: x + 1, 0))
```

is almost certainly wrong as `f(a, b)` is expecting to be passed a callable method `a` and a parameter `b`. In this case `b` is `0` and `0(0)` produces an error. Unless anticipating that error was the assignment.

So, lets assume your implementation really is:

```py
def f(a, b):
    return a(b)

print(f(lambda x: x + 1, 0))
```

That is, our method `f(a, b)` is expecting to be passed a function `a` and a parameter `b` and return the result of calling that function with that parameter.

Let's now step through multiple versions of the code **all doing the same thing** so that we can more easily see what is happening.

**Version 0:** What we start with

```py
def f(a, b):
    return a(b)
print(f(lambda x: x + 1, 0))
```

**Version 1:** break out the lambda. We can see here that our lambda accepts a single parameter `x` and returns the value `x + 1`.

```py
def f(a, b):
    return a(b)

lambda_function = lambda x: x + 1

print(f(lambda_function, 0))
```

**Version 2:** calculate the result before printing it

```py
def f(a, b):
    return a(b)

lambda_function = lambda x: x + 1
result = f(lambda_function, 0)

print(result)
```

**Version 3:** rename `f()`

```py
def def_function(a, b):
    return a(b)

lambda_function = lambda x: x + 1
result = def_function(lambda_function, 0)

print(result)
```

**Version 3:** rename parameters of `def_function()` formerly `f()`

```py
def def_function(passed_function, passed_parameter):
    return passed_function(passed_parameter)

lambda_function = lambda x: x + 1
result = def_function(lambda_function, 0)

print(result)
```

**Version 4:** calculate the result before returning it

```py
def def_function(passed_function, passed_parameter):
    result = passed_function(passed_parameter)
    return result

lambda_function = lambda x: x + 1
result = def_function(lambda_function, 0)

print(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's analyze the program step by step to understand how it works. Here's the original code for reference:

```py
def f(a, b):
    return b(b)

print(f(lambda x: x + 1, 0))
```

1. First, the function `f` is defined, which takes two arguments `a` and `b`.
2. The `return` statement inside the function specifies that the output of the function will be `b(b)`, that is, it calls the argument `b` as a function, with `b` itself as an argument.
3. The `print` statement in the following line calls the function `f` with two arguments: `lambda x: x + 1` and `0`. The lambda function takes one argument and returns it incremented by 1.
4. When the `print` line is executed, the function `f` is called with `a = lambda x: x + 1` and `b = 0`.

Now, let's analyze the call to function `f`.

with `a = lambda x: x + 1` and `b = 0`:

- `f(a, b) = f(lambda x: x + 1, 0)`
- Inside the function, `return b(b)` means calling `b` as a function with `b` as an argument. However, `b` is not a function; it's an integer (0) in this case. This will cause an error, as you cannot call an integer as if it were a function.

> Also what is the meaning of `a(b)`.

When you change the `return` statement to `return a(b)` instead of `return b(b)`, here's what happens:

```py
def f(a, b):
    return a(b)

print(f(lambda x: x + 1, 0))
```

1. The function `f` is defined, which takes two arguments `a` and `b`.
2. The `return` statement inside the function now specifies that the output of the function will be `a(b)`, that is, it calls the argument `a` as a function, with `b` as an argument.
3. The `print` statement in the following line calls the function `f` with two arguments: `lambda x: x + 1` and `0`. The lambda function takes one argument and returns it incremented by 1.
4. When the `print` line is executed, the function `f` is called with `a = lambda x: x + 1` and `b = 0`.

Now, let's analyze the call to function `f`.

with `a = lambda x: x + 1` and `b = 0`:

- `f(a, b) = f(lambda x: x + 1, 0)`
- Inside the function, `return a(b)` means calling `a` as a function with `b` as an argument. In this case, `a` is the lambda function `lambda x: x + 1`, and `b` is the integer `0`.

Since `a` is a valid function (`lambda x: x + 1`), you can call it with `b` as an argument.

So, `a(b)` is now equal to the lambda function with `b` as its argument:

`a(b) = (lambda x: x + 1)(0)`

This lambda function takes the argument `0` and increments it by `1`:

```
x = 0
x + 1 = 0 + 1 = 1
```

Thus, the lambda function returns `1`, and the whole call to `f(lambda x: x + 1, 0)` also returns `1`. So, the `print` statement will output `1`.